# How to repeatedly update the contents of a <div> by only using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I want to convert this code so that it doesn't show the value of i in prompt boxes. I need it to repeatedly update the value of i inside a dedicated `<div>`. This should occur every second, hence the delay in the loop by 1000ms. How do I convert this code then?

```
for(var i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
    setInterval(alert(i),1000);
}
```

I need it to show in here:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: You can set the `innerHTML` property of the element in an anonymous function executed by the `setInterval()` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Do** use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the element.

**Do** use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set the text content.

**Don't** use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) in loops (unless you mean to) because that will cause the callback you give to the `setInterval` to be executed `n` number of times every timeout.

**Do** use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) to stop the interval from executing when you are done.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("timer");
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  el.innerHTML = i++;
  if (i > 10) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and avoid `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.  Then you can simply not make a new timeout when you are above your maximum count.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("timer");
var i = 0;

function counter() {
  el.innerHTML = i++;
  if (i <= 10) {
    setTimeout(counter, 1000);
  }
}

counter();
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, works now. I been using what you say, but not in this same manner.